# How to implement a custom scheduler in Heron?

Tags: streaming, scheduled-tasks, apache-storm, heron

I have read the `Heron Documents` about [`Implementing a Custom Scheduler`](https://twitter.github.io/heron/docs/contributors/custom-scheduler/). And I have known that I should implement some interfaces to implement a Custom Scheduler, such as `ILauncher`, `IPacking`, `IScheduler` and `IUploader`.

I have realized my `CustomScheduler` that implemented `IScheduler` interface, and I want to using `LocalLauncher`, `LocalUploader` and `default Packing algorithm` with my custom scheduler.

What's more, I modified the heron configuration file named `scheduler.yaml` that located at `conf/local/` to use the custom scheduler. At the same time, I added the `CustomScheduler.jar` to `heron-core/lib/scheduler/`. However, there is something wrong as logs shows:

```
[2018-04-15 20:44:27 -0700] [STDERR] stderr: Exception in thread "main"   
[2018-04-15 20:44:27 -0700] [STDERR] stderr: com.twitter.heron.spi.scheduler.SchedulerException: Failed to instantiate scheduler using class 'com.zyt.heron.custom.scheduler.CustomScheduler'  
[2018-04-15 20:44:27 -0700] [STDERR] stderr:    at com.twitter.heron.scheduler.utils.LauncherUtils.getSchedulerInstance(LauncherUtils.java:120)  
[2018-04-15 20:44:27 -0700] [STDERR] stderr:    at com.twitter.heron.scheduler.SchedulerMain.runScheduler(SchedulerMain.java:382)  
[2018-04-15 20:44:27 -0700] [STDERR] stderr:    at com.twitter.heron.scheduler.SchedulerMain.main(SchedulerMain.java:218)
```

what should I do to fix this problem? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to provide your compiled .jar files to heron by **copying your jar files into the .heron/lib/** folder.

I want to implement a custom scheduler and packing algorithm **without recompiling Heron**.

I have a project called "packing" that has the maven dependencies heron.api and heron.spi as requested.

My jar is called "packing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dendencies.jar built with maven.
What works for me are the following steps summarized in a small shell-script. I run it from within my packing-project folder to the assembly-command works:

```
#!/bin/bash
mvn assembly:assembly
cp target/packing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar $HOME/.heron/lib/packing/
cp target/packing-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar $HOME/.heron/lib/scheduler/
echo "updated packing plan and scheduler"
```

Then, simply add your custom packing or scheduler to your config:

Example from the packing.yaml:

```
heron.class.packing.algorithm: com.hcep.packing.CustomPacking
```

with com.hcep.packing being my package structure in my packing-project and CustomPacking my packing class.

Answer (score 1):

The direct reason for your Exception is your custom scheduler is not packaged with the heron release.

To make your custom scheduler work, you can follow the steps below:

1. add your implementation into the directory `heron/schedulers/src/java/com/twitter/heron/scheduler`
2. update the `BUILD` file at directory `heron/schedulers/src/java`
3. add your custom scheduler building target at `tools/rules/heron_client.bzl` and `tools/rules/heron_core.bzl`

Here is an example of how local scheduler is packaged: https://github.com/apache/incubator-heron/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=heron-local-scheduler&type=

Answer (score -1):

You can develop custom scheduler for Heron - please follow any of the implementations for a scheduler in the code base.

Comment: What should I do to deploy my custom scheduler to Heron? Do I should  upload my customScheduler.jar to heron-core.jar/lib/scheduler/? Is that right?

Comment: I have edited this question with more details. Thanks for you help.